# How to register angular service worker?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

So I am creating ASP.NET MVC application with angular. For my app I need service worker, so I found that angular has it's own (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/service-worker). So I installed and found that I need to register it in order to work. I took example from github (https://github.com/webmaxru/pwatter/tree/ngsw/src/app). As I try to register and run everything I always getting this error :

[image]

I've read that I need to use HTTPS and/or production mode instead of development, so I tried various combinations and nothing worked... Could someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

This is my app.module.ts (without imports):

```
@NgModule({
    // directives, components, and pipes
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],

    // modules
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRouting,

        ImageUploadModule.forRoot(),
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        InfiniteScrollModule,
        NouisliderModule,
        ChartsModule,
        NgxPaginationModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register("\ngsw-worker.js")
    ],

    // providers
    providers: [
        PushService,
    ],

    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})  
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: a 404 ("Not Found") means whatever you're trying to load from the server doesn't exist at the location requested. We can't see your server setup so we can't check that for you.

Comment: I can see one obvious difference between your script and the example: yours uses `\ngsw-worker.js` whereas the example uses `/ngsw-worker.js`. Backslashes usually aren't ok in URLs.

Comment: @ADyson I've tried changing slashes either...

Comment: Ok well you need to look in your browser's dev tools in the Network section, see what is being requested and returning 404, and then fix it so that there's the right file at that location, or fix the code to look somewhere else. Can't really help you with that since we don't know what's being requested exactly, or what your server structure is like.

Comment: @NikasŽalias What do you have in your ngsw-config.json ??